# How can in_array work while fetching values from external URL using PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have following code which contains some keys and when someone want to get some info from my server they send that API param with the URL and then it validates with my API keys stored and returns output.

```
$get_api = $_GET['api'];
$api = array('api_key1','api_key2','api_key3','api_key4');

if(in_array($get_api,$api, true)){
   echo "Found";
} else{
   echo "Not found";
}
```

When someone pass following API param, they will see output as `found` when URL is following:

`https://www.example.com/index.php?api=api_key1`

However I have several servers where I have to host these API Keys. So I cannot manually go and add API keys every time when I have to add one. So I did the following thing. I tried to host API Keys on one server and every other server would look in that file and if found it would return `found`.

The code for that was:

API Hosted Code: (HTML)

`'api_key1','api_key2','api_key3','api_key4'`

Code which request API Keys: (PHP)

```
$get_api = $_GET['api'];
$fetch_keys = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/path-to-keys.html");
$api = array($fetch_keys);  // fetching and putting that in array

if(in_array($get_api,$api, true)){
   echo "Found";
} else{
   echo "Not found";
}
```

However, it is not working. It is returning internal error. Please can anyone guide how can I solve it or is their any better way to do it. Thanks

Comment: instead of adding it manually to a file, why not just create a small SQLite3 DB and do some authentication with normal SQL?

Comment: dump the `$api` and see if its a correct `array` variable, if not, just process `$fetch_keys` content and manually creating the array `$api` again

Comment: @zimorok I don't want to use DB. Sorry for not mentioning that in question. And about var_dump($api); yeah it return correct array.  Edit #1 the question is solved. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: how u structure the keys in `https://www.example.com/path-to-keys.html`? mostly likely, it is treated as 1 whole array like `array('api_key1,api_key2,api_key3,api_key4');` instead of `array('api_key1','api_key2','api_key3','api_key4');`. notice the `' ' `. I suggest you process the `keys.html` to create the array

Comment: @Andy If you were receiving internal error, I am a little bit skeptical about how explode() did the job for you? Is the ini setting `allow_url_fopen` set correctly?

Comment: @nice_dev I am new to PHP. Idk what was causing that in first place. I tried to debug that. But no use. But now explode() seems to be working. With my code var_dump($api); was getting correct array but in_array() was not working.

Comment: @Andy Fair enough. My advice is to not make a URL return you all keys. If any intruder gets this URL, he/she could just replay those different kinds of keys to gather information. You can make an authentication layer to make it secure.

Comment: @nice_dev since I am new, idk much in detail about authentication. But I have encrypted the api keys in html with some other keys. And they are decrypted on my server while using file_get_contents and that's how it is working now. If you can give me some tutorial guide about authentication, that would be helpful.

Comment: @zimorok I know that. I did tried to change that too, by assigning unique values to every key in array. and calling them in php. But that too not worked. But explode() worked like charm.

Comment: @Andy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719676/implementing-simple-authentication-for-php-rest-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $api= explode (',', $fetch_keys);

Comment: Thank you @mohammed-azar, it is working. Just had to change html code a bit. instead of `'api_key1','api_key2','api_key3','api_key4'` it should have been `api_key1,api_key2,api_key3,api_key4`. Doing that, it works. Thanks!